# Trying to call non-existent action creates a perpetual request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've encountered an unusual situation in my `MVC` web app. When calling a non-existent action in any of the controllers in my app, instead of getting the expected 404 error, it actually creates a request that just sits there for ever, actually doing this several times causes the `IIS Worker` to balloon to over 500MB and I have to kill it in the `Task Manager` to keep using my app. I've looked at `Routes` and `Global.asax` and find nothing of interest. This is a `DDD` app with a `ServiceLocator` and `Unity` for `DI`, but those are not doing anything with the `MVC` stack, just my `Solution` `Projects`. Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being my `Error Logger`, running `async`, was not ever completing the task and because I was `await`ing it, it sat there forever.